# mysql database issue mentor and mentees

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

Sorry for asking this but I need to know how to do this:
Lets say that a mentor has 10 multiple mentees, is there a way to reduce the amount of fields I need to put in my database (mentee1-mentee10) ?

theres a mentor and student table in my DB

does it has something to do with one-to-many relationships?

sorry if this is too little information im giving, i'd provide more description on what im trying to ask here if you'd like

Comment: depends - can a mentee have multiple mentors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a student can have multiple mentors, then you can use a [M-N relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) and introduce a 3rd table `student_mentor` table that will map a `student id` to a `mentor id`.

```
--------------------------
| student_id | mentor_id |
--------------------------
```

Now, if you need to allow at most 10 mentors, then you'd have to build some [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) that will prevent inserting/updating of records that will violate this restriction.

To conclude, yes, you can reduce the field redundancy, however if you want to keep the 10 mentees constraint you will need to do some extra work.

Comment: This answers a different question altogether.

Comment: The question is not complete, so I replied with one of the possibilities of solving the problem. That's why I started my answer with an `If`.

Comment: By that logic, why have you not included information about the `mentee` and `mentor`s relationships with other *possible* tables?  Should your "if" not have come as an addendum to a solution that answers the OPs question as it stands?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, especially on the last question. I get it, you disagree with my answer, that's fine, just down-vote it, even flag it if you think it's harmful. There's no reason for us to start a debate here on what's good and bad, it's not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 tables, `mentor` and `mentee`, you could give your `mentee` a `mentorId` pointing to the `mentor` table.

And yes - this is very much a one-to-many relationship :)

If however, students can mentor many students AND students can BE mentored by many students, then you have a many-to-many relationship.  These are usually modelled by whats called [Junction Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Comment: is it? multiple mentors per mentee is a thing. and vice versa.

Comment: Conceptually, yes.  In this instance, as it is not mentioned, there is no need to confuse things.  If the OP wants a system with multiple mentors per mentee, he can mention that and the question becomes a different one - with a different answer.

Comment: Looks like you agree with my answer, after all :)

Comment: Actually, no.  I dont.  And stop trolling - it makes you look like a child and it's not productive or helpful in any way.

Comment: How do you call it arguing my answer is not good and then including the same idea in yours?